# Limit iPhone charging current

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, usb, battery, charging

I use the included lightning to usb-c cable to charge my iPhone 12 by connecting it to my macbook pro (2017). I've heard that reducing the charging current is potentially beneficial to the battery. If so, is there a way for me to limit the amount of current available to the iPhone (for example, to the standard 1A)?

Current current data:

```
  Available Current (mA)：   500
  Required Current (mA)：    500
  Extra Operating Current (mA)： 1900
  Sleep Current (mA)：   2400
```

Comment: It's already self limiting, it will slow down over 50% charge & then stop at 80% until your usual disconnect time. It's also only running at the standard 500mA iPhone max anyway.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for pointing that out! I compared this to a SSD and confirmed that the iPhone is indeed only drawing 500mA if the data reported is accurate. But if it only uses 500mA, why does it have the higher extra operating current / sleep current?

Comment: That's what the MBP can output if requested. I don't have an MBP here to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to reduce the amount of current available to the iPhone as the iPhone itself will not draw more power than it needs or more power than is "good for it".

If you still want to do this even though it is not a good idea, you cannot do it on the Mac.

Comment: While the OP shouldn't worry about short-term damage to a battery or starting a fire, it's still an excellent idea to avoid fast charging if you're looking to prolong the lifespan of a battery. See e.g. figure 3 of [this](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-401a-fast-and-ultra-fast-chargers) article. I personally put a high value on the lifespan of my battery, and always limit current by using the old 5 W chargers, or hacks to achieve even slower charging.

Comment: There's something missing from your argument I think. You refer to figure 3 in the article, which shows that if you charge at a higher rate than 1C, you're more than linearly degrading the battery capacity over time. I.e. if you value your battery lifespan, don't charge it faster than 1C. However, Apple's Fast Charging feature is advertised as "charge to 50% in 30 minutes" - which is exactly the rate of 1C.

Comment: Quoting from the article: “The longevity can further be prolonged by charging and discharging below 1C; 0.8C is the recommended rate.” Moreover, fast charging usually results in higher temperature, whether directly in the battery or in nearby power circuitry, which usually conducts to the battery. And temperature is enemy #1 of a battery, which is also the reason I never use wireless chargers.

Comment: I’m still not convinced by that argument. The charge rate they talk about is the average over many charges - you’re not fast charging all the time, so your average charge rate is not 1C - it’s considerably less. Whether or not a harmful temperature is present depends on how well the thermals of the phone are designed. I have seen no evidence that there’s any meaningful loss of capacity over a reasonable amount of time (for example 3 years) by disabling fast charge religiously.

Comment: I admit I’m way more paranoid than most people when it comes to battery lifespan since I live in a warm country and a battery swap is twice as expensive (in dollars, never mind a purchasing power matched comparison) as in say the US. I just do what it takes to lessen battery degradation over the 3-4 years I keep my phone. Doesn’t mean I wouldn’t fast charge if SoC was low and I was pressed for time, but I do try to plan ahead to avoid it. Also, it’s plain to anyone who touches a phone while fast (or wireless) charging that it is warmer than on a regular (5W) wired charge.

Comment: Of course it’s warmer. It would have been a problem if it wasn’t warmer. Warmer does not mean it’s harmful.

Comment: Actually it does, see table 3 [here](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-808-how-to-prolong-lithium-based-batteries): a battery constantly kept at 100% charge and 40ºC degrades to 65% capacity over a year, vs. 80% capacity at 25ºC. Also, it's not about averages: charging at 1C half the time and 0.5C the other half does not produce equivalent degradation as charging at 0.75C every time. Every 1C (or higher) charge eats away a little bit at the battery capacity, even more so at warmer temperatures. Anyone is free to fast charge as often as they'd like, but it does affect battery lifespan.

Comment: You need to take that table into the context here. Is your iPhone 15 degrees hotter when fast charging compared to normal charging? Is it that much warmer 24/7? (No, of course not - so the degradation is much much smaller). And yes, of course it does not give 0.75C - I wrote that earlier in my comment - the relationship is not linear. And yes, of course it affects lifespan - everyone agrees about that. The interesting thing is how much, it affects life span. That’s what you need to know to judge whether it is worthy it for you to spend time on disabling Fast Charge.